# How to click this button using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I cant click on a button on a webpage using selenium. Does anyone know how i can click it, I've tried every single method i can think of and i cant quite get it to work.

I've tried XPATH, ID's, searching for the text on the button, i've tried copy pasting code from other people.

This is the button i want to press:

```
<div id="sbWatchHeaderNext">
          <a href="https://pf.entertainow.com//f/p/enter?plid=5ad013747591fd8f488b4568$152501860$sO**ocW2WJU3*d1YTbuBew&amp;euid=59cad72c28db997a4cfe4ee3$152501860$GbU3GsQ8lz0CwYCEDtNCTw&amp;kc=1&amp;rock=%7B%22fid%22%3A%225b60c7087591fdf6268b4567%22%2C%22puid%22%3A%2239511142%22%7D&amp;paper=bE43FLvdUsdYyz6w3CV7mYJkahm-ZuXLedpu2XSnAc1nOB-mCRb-ZPN6ppyszpEm-rxaZmMf6bYoMWs90vR61e5vZOucr-eF6yd-N-aovwGtEdRz9ZYnYs4h2Ior_ZB5p4TP_NLGh_SDgSXfSTNY6YaOr2oUJ7jRvRN9Kw_tQ0_wDz0AshpZi4EskNE2lzBoQxX3yELRdF5QIR4_pS0hW3CT1-x5ls_BNfa9N5rAPNL91pDlh3D2IfhXNPSwt3p4ffhkL9OPiMU&amp;urrMet=null&amp;encl=528769679">Next</a>
      </div>
```

This is the code I currently have that isn't working:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue Watching')]")))
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
```

Please if you have any suggestions i should try, let me know :)

With some methods i would get absolutely no errors in console but nothing would happen on the webpage, and with others i would get "Message: no such element: unable to locate element:..." and things like that in my console.

Comment: The button became a real button HAHA, sorry im new here, you can see the code if you inspect element it

Comment: Also i have made sure that my code is tabbed into the correct page, and i definitely can mess with other buttons on the same page

Comment: Can you please post the html of the button.

Comment: Yeah sorry the html for some reason just made it show up as "button" im not sure how to post the HTML but if you right click and inspect element the blue text that says " Next " you can see the exact HTML of the button. Sorry im new here lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. To `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#sbWatchHeaderNext>a[href^='https://pf.entertainow.com//f/p/enter?plid']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='sbWatchHeaderNext']/a[starts-with(@href, 'https://pf.entertainow.com//f/p/enter?plid') and text()='Next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Gotcha, sorry im new here :)